# Trying to insert the Element into ArrayList but, instead of inserting its updating with the current value

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a below piece of code where I fetch the json data and pass it to the another method. Data will be keep changing on daily basis. Here, I want to retain my old Data, but somehow I am unable to do it.

Code to save the value:

```
json = getAllHistory(settings.getRapidView(),sprint.getId(), 
        settings.getCredentials(),settings.getBaseUrl());

List<History> historyList = new ArrayList<>();

Double completedIssues = ClientUtil.getJsonValue(json,sprint.getId(),"completedIssues");

Double allIssues = ClientUtil.getJsonValue(json,sprint.getId(),"allIssues");

Double remainingIssues = completedIssues-allIssues;

if (remainingIssues > 0) {

    History history = new History();

    history.setMiliseconds(ZonedDateTime.now().toInstant().toEpochMilli());
    history.setCompletedIssues(completedIssues);
    history.setAllIssues(allIssues);
    history.setRemainingIssues(remainingIssues);
    historyList.add(history);

    sprintdata.gethistory().addAll(historyList);

    sprintdata.setHistory(historyList);
}
```

Code to make the Rest call:

```
public static String getAllHistory(String rapidView, Long sprintId, String base64Credentials,String baseUrl) {
    try
    {
        String query = String.format(GET_URL_DATA, rapidView, sprintId);
        query=baseUrl+query;

        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(getHeader(base64Credentials));

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.exchange(query, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);

        String outputJson= result.getBody();
        return outputJson;
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        // TODO: handle exception
        return null;
    }
}
```

Code to get the specific Json value:

```
public static Double getJsonValue(String json, Long sprintId, String field) {

    try{
        return new GsonBuilder().
                create().
                fromJson(json, JsonObject.class).
                getAsJsonObject("contents").
                getAsJsonObject(field).
                get("value").
                getAsDouble();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I can't find the error on my own, so please help me.

I apologize for my mistake.

Comment: Never catch exception without logging it out

Comment: Yes you are right

Comment: `sprintdata.gethistory().addAll(historyList); sprintdata.setHistory(historyList);` .... huh? What's your logic here?

Answer (score 1):

A list of one element is created.

Then to the old history list of sprintdata: all items of the new list are added (1):

```
sprintdata.gethistory().addAll(historyList);
```

Then the old sprintdata history list is replaced with the new one of 1 element:

```
sprintdata.setHistory(historyList);
```

So the sole thing to do would be: add one element to the old history list.

```
sprintdata.gethistory().add(history);
```

Comment: should I remove this line:                                                                                sprintdata.gethistory().addAll(historyList);

Comment: Yes and setHistory and remove the historyList.